# How to check if a pointer can traverse a possible path given a fixed number of moves

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I am trying to solve this problem on Hackerrank:

[image]

I have this input:

```
........#....#..#..#....#...#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.....
..#..#..#.#....#..#.....#......#..##...........##.
.........#.###.##...#.....##......###............#
....##........#..#.#.#......#...#.##.......##.....
.................###...#.#...#......#.#.#.#.#...#.
.........#.....#...........##....#.#.#.##.....##..
.....#.##............#....#......#..#..#...##.....
.#.......###....#.#..##.##.#...##...#........#...#
..#.##..##..........#..........##.....##..........
#.#..##......#.#.#..##.###...#.........###..#...#.
.#..#..............#...#........#..#...#....#..#..
##..#..#........#....#........#...#.#......#.....#
#.#.......#.#..#...###..#..#.##...#.##.......#...#
#.#...#...#.....#....#......##.#.#.........#....#.
.#..........#......##..#....#....#.#.#..#..###....
#.#............#.##..#.##.##......###......#..#..#
.#..#.##...#.#......................#........#....
.....#....#.#..........##.#.#................#....
##............#.#......####...#.........#..##..#..
....#..##..##...#.........##..##....#..#.##...#...
.#........#...#..#...........#.###.....##.....##..
.......#..#..##...#..###.....#..##.........#......
...#......#..#...........###...............#......
...##.###.#.#....#...#..#.#.#....#....#.##.#...#..
..........#.......#..#..#...###....##.....#..#....
.............##.##.#.......#.#....#.......#..#..#.
.......#........#.....#....##...#...#.#...#.#.##..
.....#..#..#........#..#.....#...#.##.#....#...#..
....................#.#...#....###...###...##...#.
##.#.....##.....#..#.#.#...........#.#.##...#..#.#
#...........#....#.##...#.#.....#...#.....#.#.....
..#..##...#........#.##..#.....##.......#...#.#.#.
......#....#...##...........#..#.......#.##.......
......#..#..#.###..........#...#...........#..#...
....#.#..#..#.#.#...#.......#...#.##......#.......
....#.......#..#........#...#.#...#......#.......#
.#....##...#.#..#....#.#.##........#..#.#.........
#....#.......#..##......##...............#..#.##..
...#..##.......#.....#....#...#.#......#..##..###.
.....#...#...#...#...#...#..##...#..#.............
....##......#...#..#...#...#.#....#.....#..#.##...
...##.......#..##.....#........#.#....#...#.......
..#...#....#...#.###......#................#......
...#...###...#..##...###.....................#....
.....#....#....#...#.#.#.##....##......#....##....
...#.###...##.........#..........#.##.#.....#.....
##..#...#.........#.......#......##...........####
...###.#..........#.....#####........#..#.#.#...#.
...#..#.....#..##.##.#.....##...#...#.#.....#...##
.##.......#.##....#............#..................
#.....#.........#.#.........#..###....##...##.....
#....#.....#...#.....#.##...##...####........#....
#...........#..#...#........#.##..##..#...#.#.....
..#.#................#......###..##.#.#...##...#..
.#.#....#..#............#....#......#............#
..#..#...#.#.#...#...........#.......##.#...#.#...
#..........#.....#.....#......#.......#.#...##....
.......#...........#...........#....#............#
...####.#.....#.##.....#.......##.#..#......#.....
.#..#.....#..#......#.............#.#.#..##...#...
..#.#.#.........#...#..#.......#................##
.#..##.#.#...#.............#..#..........#..#...#.
....#........#......#...###..#.#..................
#..#..#.....#.#.#...##....##........#........#....
.....#.#.......##.......#.....#........#..##..#...
#.#.##........#..##.#..#.#...#........#.#......#..
....#.#.#.......#.##.##...##...#..#.###...#.#.#...
.....##.#....#........#....#.#........#.#.#.....#.
.....#..##..#.#....#.......#...#.#.###.........#.#
#.....#.##..#.......###.........#..##..#......##..
```

70 rows and the maxTime is 2244

This is my strategy but it works for some test cases:

```
import math
import collections

def reachTheEnd(grid, maxTime):
    
    # Write your code here
    grid = [i for i in grid]
    yes = 'Yes'
    no = 'No'
    counter = 0
    
    for i in grid:
        counter += i.count('.')
    
    if maxTime <= counter:
        return yes
        
    elif i != i[::-1]:
        return no 
    else:
        return no
    print(counter)
```

This is a BFS problem but I couldn't figure out the logic. I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea of breadth-first search is that you (1) don't visit the same node twice, and (2) continuously maintain a list of nodes you haven't visited, split up by timeslice. Eventually, you visit all visitable nodes, and for any node you do visit, you visit it in as few steps as possible.

In the following algorithm, we create a cache to satisfy (1) and a queue to satisfy (2). Each timeslice, we examine each element of the queue, and replace the queue entirely with a new queue, composed of elements discovered during that timeslice. Whenever we discover a new element, we add it to the cache along with the timeslice on which it was first found - this, then, must be the quickest route to that new element.

If we either run out of time or run out of new cells to explore before reaching the destination, then we fail. Otherwise, we succeed. We can check that by simply encoding our exit conditions and checking if we've visited the destination by the time we exit the `while` loop.

```
def reachTheEnd(grid, maxTime):
    # mark what the coordinates of the destination are
    destination = (len(grid) - 1, len(grid[-1]) - 1)
    # initialize
    #   - a step counter
    #   - a cache of visited cells on the grid
    #   - a queue of not-yet-visited cells that are adjacent to visited cells
    counter = 0
    cache = {(0, 0): 0}
    queue = [(0, 0)]
    # perform breadth-first search on the current queue, moving forward one
    # timeslice. On each timeslice, we take one 'step' forward in any direction
    # towards a newly-accessible tile on the grid.
    # our 'exit' conditions are
    #   - we run out of time
    #   - there is no path to the end of the maze
    #   - we reach the end
    while counter < maxTime and len(queue) > 0 and destination not in cache:
        counter += 1
        new_queue = []
        for (x, y) in queue:
            # check adding to path in all directions (up, down, left, right)
            # If the step is
            #   - not out-of-bounds
            #   - not a wall
            #   - not already visited
            # then add it to the cache with the current step count, as this is
            # is the most quickly we can reach it. Also add it to the queue of 
            # cells to investigate on the next timeslice.
            for (dx, dy) in [(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)]:
                (nx, ny) = (x + dx, y + dy)
                if 0 <= nx < len(grid) \
                        and 0 <= ny < len(grid[nx]) \
                        and grid[nx][ny] == '.' \
                        and (nx, ny) not in cache:
                    cache[(nx, ny)] = counter
                    new_queue.append((nx, ny))
        queue = new_queue
    # by the time the loop exits, either we've failed to reach the end, 
    # or the end is in the cache with the quickest possible path to it.
    if destination in cache:
        return "Yes"
    else:
        return "No"
```

A possible optimization would be to move the "have we reached destination yet" to inside the innermost `for` loop, which would save processing the rest of the queue on that timeslice. However, this would make the code slightly more complicated (and thus less useful for explaining the concept of BFS) and provide only a minimal time save.

---

Note that for the big 70x50 grid you've provided, there's no way to actually reach the lower-right square (it's a small island surrounded by walls). It can reach cell (67, 49) by timeslice 117, which is as close as it gets, but can't get around the wall.

Comment: Very nice implementation